# postgresql slow: primary key on 80M row table

Tags: postgresql

I've a 64GB RAM machine, 20 CPUs, and this is the command to create a primary key over a table with 80M rows:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY wikipedia_article ADD CONSTRAINT pagelinks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (language, title);
```

The problem I've got with this is that:

- only 1 CPU is used up to 100% (avg load 99%), the rest aren't used at all
- the write speed during the primary key creation is quite low, 2.6 M/s, read speed missing completely from the report produced by pg_activity

This is the table structure:

```
                          Table "public.wikipedia_article"
    Column    |       Type       | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------+------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 language     | text             | not null  | extended |              |
 title        | text             | not null  | extended |              |
 langcount    | integer          |           | plain    |              |
 othercount   | integer          |           | plain    |              |
 totalcount   | integer          |           | plain    |              |
 lat          | double precision |           | plain    |              |
 lon          | double precision |           | plain    |              |
 importance   | double precision |           | plain    |              |
 osm_type     | character(1)     |           | extended |              |
 osm_id       | bigint           |           | plain    |              |
 infobox_type | text             |           | extended |              |
 population   | bigint           |           | plain    |              |
 website      | text             |           | extended |              |
Has OIDs: no
```

The import happens automatically via pg_restore, this is the source

http://www.nominatim.org/data/wikipedia_article.sql.bin

Any ideas on what I can try to make things faster? I changed the value of the conf varible "maintenance_work_mem" to half of the RAM size. I also tried to change some of the kernel settings, with no joy:

```
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=17179869184
sysctl -w kernel.shmall=1048576
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1 
sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

The OS is running on a VM, in Digital Ocean, on SSD drives, I was expecting this could work faster for such a VM configuration.

Server info: PostgreSQL 9.3.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4, 64-bit

Many thanks, VG

Comment: BTW: I think this is a rather strange choice of PK. Aren't there any numerical ("surrogate") ids present in the table(s) ?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL uses for one statement one CPU - so CPU utilization 100% is expected. You can try to set `maintenance_work_mem` for some higher value. The default is too low - you can try '2GB' for example.